# MiKTeX is not working? miktex-makemf did not succeed

Tags: bibtex, errors

I am new a latex and try to write my thesis right now (I use this template https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). I use it since a year and everything went fine. Since a week. The files won´t compile. I reinstalled Texstudio and MikTeX (updated) and all my other files started to work exept my thesis files. I then made an overleaf account. Did not work there either. I tried this https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/zhaw-thesis-template/pgpcwwyfqkhv which works on overleaf, but it does not work at my Texstudio nor Texmaker on the computer.

Everytime when i fixed one proble several aother seemed to open and now I am on a dead end. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me here.

I basically says:
Process started: "C:\miktex\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe"  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "thesis".tex

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\rtres\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

log:

- Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
- Overfull \hbox (0.28949pt too wide) in paragraph
- \headheight to low.
- Overfull \vbox (8.34636pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
- name{cite.0@musso} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

I read several things about overfull hbox and vbox here and there are peopel with similar problems but it doesn´t really helped.

Best Ralph

Comment: Overfull boxes aren't fatal errors.  Worry about them later. stop reinstalling and look for clues what is wrong.  Make a copy of your thesis and the move \end{document} until you find the place where it breaks.

Comment: Are those lines the only thing in the log? It seems like there is a 'real' error somewhere (apart from the warnings that you mention), so that error should be in the log as well.

Comment: First thanks for the answers.

Comment: It does say that it exited with erros but there are non listed in the log. Only badboxe and warning regarding bibtex. When I open the directory, where everthing is stored, I can see that the pdf file first is created and then it disappears. The Template works in overleaf (pdf is created) but fails one copied into my TexStudio, so does my thesis. The theis also does not work in overleaf.

Comment: I tried Ulrike Fischer´s \end{document}  and moved it directly under \begin document this time it says it exited normaly but " it does not look like a valid pdf document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation" -> then it is stuck. -> finally i could at least recreate the titlepage.

Comment: -> it starts to crash one I include the first chapter and I have to remove symbol section.

Comment: Hello there. i think I finally found something. This T$\Psi$C causes it to fail. So Greek letters were the Problem? How can I add one then?

Comment: \Thanks all for your help usepackage[LGRgreek, italic]{mathastext} finally solved the problem. I do not know why it wokred months before without it but know it wokrs.